# Image title always appears. How do I make it disappear or be hidden after I click on the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an `<img>` tag inside listviewlist.when when I hover over this button the title appears & then disappears. When I click on the button showing a modal popup after I close the popup, the title is does not disappear. See attached image. How can I make the title disappear. I am using listviewlist inside an update panel. 
ASPX code:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <div id="dvTC" runat="server" style="width:18px;" class="mv-action">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTC" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TermsAndCondition") %>' 
                                   CommandName="TermsCondition" runat="server">
            <img src="../../../Images/MuslimVoucher/lupe.png" width="14" height="14" 
                 alt="magnifier" title="Terms & Conditions" />
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</td>
```

Show popup server-side code

```
protected void lvGiftVoucher_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
if (e.CommandName == "TermsCondition") 
 this.ModalPopupTC.Show(); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show the code of popup.

Comment: ` protected void lvGiftVoucher_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.CommandName == "TermsCondition")
        {

            this.ModalPopupTC.Show();
        }

    }   `

Comment: Show the code of ModalPopupTc in question don't include in comments.

Comment: popup code added.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<img src="../../../Images/MuslimVoucher/lupe.png" width="14" height="14" 
             alt="magnifier" title="Terms & Conditions"  onmouseover="this.title='';" />
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: On mouse over Title is not showing if i use your code `onmouseover="this.title='';"` . My issue is when i hover on icon title appear & disappear but when i click on icon then title stay there.

Comment: I see your trouble, the onmouseout event occurs when the mouse pointer is moved out of an element, or out of one of its children. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: "onmouseout "  event same thing happened. After click on icon Title stay there.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested this issue on?

Comment: I am using 'Mozilla firefox'

Comment: Try another browser like ie or chrome or both.

Comment: Chrome is working fine but mozilla & IE is not working

Comment: There must be a bug on your system or something. I'd advise that you create a new project and move your code to it then test from there. Something is not right there - especially since it works fine on Chrome "My thoughts." - Also make sure you have all the latest updates for your system (I take it you are on Windows)